# Why will my program terminate when I input a number which exceeds the max number of linked list?

Tags: c

I encounter a problem when I use the function `update()`, written by me, supposed that there are three nodes of my linked list, Part number is no.1, no.5, and no.10, when I update information of these parts and input the Part number between the max part number and the min part number of  linked list, it works. But it doesn't work when I input a Part number which exceeds the max part number of linked list, and the program even terminates. What is the cause for the program to terminate? How could I revise it?

Following is my code:

```
/* Maintains a parts database (linked list version) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "readline.h"

#define NAME_LEN 25

struct part {
    int num;
    char name[NAME_LEN + 1];
    int on_hand;
    struct part *next;
};

struct part *inventory = NULL;
int num_parts = 0; //number of parts currently stored//

struct part *find_part(int number);
void insert(void);
void search(void);
void update(void);
void print(void);

/************************************************************************
*main: Prompts the user to enter an operation code, then calls a function
       to perform the requested action. Repeats until the user enters the
       command 'q'. Print an error message if the user enters an illegal
       code.
************************************************************************/
       
int main(void) {
    char code;
    
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter operation code: ");
        scanf(" %c" ,&code);
        while (getchar() != '\n')           // skips to end of line//
            ;
        switch (code) {
            case 'i':
                insert();
                break;
            case 'u':
                update();
                break;
            case 'p':
                print();
                break;
            case 'q':
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Illegal code\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void insert(void) {
    
    struct part *cur, *pre, *new_node;
    
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct part));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Database is full; can't add more parts.\n");
        return;
    }
    
    printf("Enter part number: ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->num);
    
    for (pre = NULL, cur = inventory;
         (cur != NULL) && (new_node->num) > (cur->num);
          pre = cur, cur = cur ->next)
        ;
        
    if (cur != NULL && new_node->num == cur->num) {
        printf("Part already exists\n");
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    printf("Enter Part name: ");
    read_line(new_node->name, NAME_LEN);
    printf("Enter quantity on hand: ");
    scanf("%d" , &new_node->on_hand);
    
    new_node->next = cur;
    printf("%p", new_node->next); //test
    if (pre == NULL)
        inventory = new_node;
    else
        pre->next = new_node;
}

void update(void) {
    
    int number, change;
    struct part *p;
    
    printf("Enter the part number you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    
    for (p = inventory; (p != NULL) && (number > (p->num)); p = p->next)
        printf("%d\n", p->num);
    printf("now pointer point to no.%d\n", p->num);

    if (p->num == number) {
        printf("Enter change in quantity on hand: ");
        scanf("%d", &change);
        p->on_hand = ((p->on_hand) + change);
        printf("Already changed\n");
        print();
        return;
    } else
        printf("No.%d Part is not found.\n", number);
}

void print(void) {
    
    struct part *p;
    
    printf("Part Number    Part Name          Quantity on hand\n");
    for (p = inventory; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        printf("%6d           %-25s%7d\n", p->num, p->name, p->on_hand);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting a silent segmentation fault. On most systems you will get an error message if a program running on the command line exits due to a segmentation fault (On Linux is usually looks like `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`), however this message can usually be disabled, modified, or omitted due to the configuration of the terminal. Segmentation faults are caused by attempting to read memory from a pointer that points to data outside of the current process.

As mentioned by @MOehm the issue is that update reads too far and attempts to dereference `NULL`. It is an easy fit to just add an extra check after your for loop.

```c
for (p = inventory ; (p != NULL)&&(number > (p->num)); p = p->next)
    printf("%d\n" , p->num);

if (p == NULL) {
    printf("No node with part number %d exists\n", number);
    return;
}

printf("now pointer point to no.%d\n" , p->num);
```

Comment: This will work but it doesn't check the case that an update is called before an insert, because the for loop initializer itself is performing a dereference.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code worth noting. In your update function you don't ever check if p is a valid pointer in case the function is called before a list is created. This will crash your for loop `&(number > (p->num))`. You also aren't clearing your input stream after using scanf and this can work a lot of the times but in my case when I tested it with insert the next read failed. Lastly as pointed out you're de-referencing the pointer p within your for loop before you know p is even valid  `printf("%d\n" , p->num);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define NAME_LEN 25

struct part{
    int num;
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    int on_hand;
    struct part *next;
};

struct part *inventory = NULL;
int num_parts = 0; //number of parts currently stored//

struct part *find_part(int number);
void insert(void);
void search(void);
void update(void);
void print(void);

/************************************************************************
*main: Prompts the user to enter an operation code, then calls a function
       to perform the requested action. Repeats until the user enters the
       command 'q'. Print an error message if the user enters an illegal
       code.
************************************************************************/
       
int main(void){
    char code;
    
    for(;;){
        printf("Enter operation code: ");
        scanf(" %c" ,&code);
        while (getchar() != '\n')           // skips to end of line//
            ;
        switch (code){
            case 'i' : insert();
                break;
            case 'u' : update();
                break;
            case 'p' : print();
                break;
            case 'q' : return 0;
            default: printf("Illegal code\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void clearinput(void){
    while(fgetc(stdin)!='\n');
}
void insert(void){
    
    struct part *cur, *pre, *new_node;
    
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct part));
    if (new_node == NULL){
        printf("Database is full; can't add more parts.\n");
        return;
    }
    
    printf("Enter part number: ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->num);
    
    for ( pre = NULL,cur = inventory;
         (cur != NULL) && (new_node->num) > (cur->num);
          pre = cur,cur = cur ->next)
        ;
        
    if( cur != NULL && new_node->num == cur->num){
        printf("Part already exists\n");
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    clearinput();
    printf("Enter Part name: ");
    
    read_line(new_node->name, NAME_LEN);
    printf("Enter quantity on hand: ");
    scanf("%d" , &new_node->on_hand);
    
    new_node->next = cur;
    printf("%p",new_node->next); //test
    if (pre == NULL)
        inventory = new_node;
    else
        pre->next = new_node;
}

void update(void){
    
    int number , change;
    struct part *p;
    
    printf("Enter the part number you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    
    p = inventory;
    assert(p);
    
    for (; (p != NULL)&&(number > (p->num)); p = p->next){
        assert(p);
        printf("%d\n" , p->num);
    }
        
    
    printf("now pointer point to no.%d\n" , p->num);

    if (p->num == number){
        printf("Enter change in quantity on hand: ");
        scanf("%d",&change);
        p->on_hand = ((p->on_hand) + change);
        printf("Already changed\n");
        print();
        return;
    }else{
        printf("No.%d Part is not found.\n",number);
    }
}

void print(void){
    
    struct part *p;
    
    printf("Part Number    Part Name          Quantity on hand\n");
    for ( p = inventory; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        printf("%6d           %-25s%7d\n",p->num,p->name,p->on_hand);
}
```